# Can Chrome run angular progressive web app on iOS?

Tags: ios, angular, google-chrome

I am going to develop a web app using angular and google web API. I am curious if it can be run also on iOS? Are there any thing which are different from that run on Android I need to pay attentions when develop the app?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari has added support for PWA from IOS 11.3. If you are using previous versions of Safari. IT won't work. From IOS 11.3, It supports these 3 features

- Web App Manifest
- Service Worker
- Cache API

Adding to Home screen is not yet supported.

Here is the comparsion for PWA between Chrome and Safari. https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7